# Array value as index

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array

```
$term = array(
  0 => array(
    'id'=>'0902001',
    'name'=>'bob',
    'cgpa'=>'3.81',
  ),
  1 => array(
    'id'=>'0902002',
    'name'=>'jhon',
    'cgpa'=>'3.52',
  ),
);
```

I want to make a new array that the id will be the index for cgpa of new array.

```
$new_arr = array(
    '0902001' => '3.81',
    '0902002' => '3.52',
);
```

Thanks!

Comment: So go ahead and do it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because Stack Overflow is not http://rentacoder.com/free-coders

Comment: Hey I want an array, too. Where's my array? Why don't I have an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you

```
for ($i=0, $c = count($term); $i<$c; ++$i) {
   $new_arr[$term[$i]['id']] = $term[$i]['cgpa'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// for old php version
$new_arr = array();
foreach($term as $value){
   $new_arr[$value['id']] = $value['cgpa'];
}

// for php 5.5+
$new_arr = array_column($term, 'cgpa', 'id');
```

Comment: +1 for the use of array_column()